# Why does Qt add more than three columns when I use restoreState() on a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

My code looks somehow like the following:

```
table = QTableWidget()
table.horizontalHeader().restoreState(settings.value("savedState"))
table.setColumnCount(3)

settings.setValue("savedState", table.horizontalHeader().saveState())
```

If I run it the first time it there are only 3 column headers. The second time there are 6 and the third 9... The strange thing is `table.columnCount()` is always 3. If i remove `table.setColumnCount(3)` there are no columns at all.

Why is this happening and is it a bug or intentional?

#### UPDATE

Adding `table.clearContents()` before `table.setColumnCount(3)` made it work. I still think it's a bug.

Comment: I would agree that it's probably a bug.  Have you submitted it to Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which platform and what Qt version is this? http://chaos.troll.no/~hhartz/tablecolumns.tar seems to work fine using latest Qt 4.5

Comment: In that case it appears that this problem is fixed in a later version than the one you're using. You might want to try the PyQt 4.5 snapshot to see if this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What happens with?

```
table = QTableWidget();
table.setColumnCount(3);
table.horizontalHeader().restoreState(settings.value("savedState"));
```